# How to pass the results of a local MSSQL query into the query string for a linked MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-update, linked-server

**Background**:

I am working on a project which generates documents based on the contents of a remote MySQL (v8) database . To accomplish this, the program uses a local MSSQL (2017) database with a link to the remote MySQL db.

**Issue**:

I need to update the MySQL database based the contents of a query from the MSSQL as follows:

```
    EXEC('UPDATE LinkedMySQLDB.TableToUpdate AS a SET a.MySQLField=''updated'' WHERE a.ID IN (LocalMSSQLDB.LocalTable.ID) ;') AT LinkedMySQLServer
```

However, every time I try this it throws an error at:

```
    (LocalMSSQLDB.LocalTable.ID)
```

**Question**:

Is there a way to pass the results of a local query into the query string for the remote database?

Or, is there a different approach that is recommended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the values of LocalMSSQLDB.LocalTable.ID on MySQL server. That is not possible.

You could use a variable to calculate the statement.
In the example below I use some other names for the databases and fields. But you should get the general idea. By using concat I combine text parts with the result of the subqueries converted to a comma separated list using STRING_AGG.

```
declare @strSQL varchar(200);
select @strSQL=concat('UPDATE test.test set text=''updated'' WHERE ID in (',(SELECT STRING_AGG(ID, N', ') FROM [SQLTest].dbo.tblTest),');');
EXEC(@strSQL) AT MYSQL2;
```

This part `(SELECT STRING_AGG(ID, N', ') FROM [SQLTest].dbo.tblTest)` returns a string. If the local table contains the ID's 1 and 2, the result will be `1, 2`. Concatenated with `'UPDATE test.test set text=''updated'' WHERE ID in ('` and `');'` the final result will be:

```
UPDATE test.test set text='updated' WHERE ID in (1, 2);
```

When this is send to the MySQL server named MYSQL2, you get the desired result.

On your servers it would be something like:

```
declare @strSQL varchar(200);
select @strSQL=concat('LinkedMySQLDB.TableToUpdate AS a SET a.MySQLField=''updated'' WHERE ID in (',(SELECT STRING_AGG(ID, N', ') FROM LocalMSSQLDB..LocalTable),');');
EXEC(@strSQL) AT LinkedMySQLServer;
```

Be sure to make room for all your id's in @strSQL. 200 characters might not be enough.